# Mysql query get single order

Tags: php, mysql

hi guys please help me.

i want to get customer with single order.

i have customer table.

in my customer table i have

`cu_id, cu_fname and cu_lname, cu_datecreated`

and i have order table.

in my order tablei have

`o_id, cu_id, cu_dateorder`

here is the table

**customer**

```
cu_id|cu_fname|cu_lname|cu_datecreated

1    |joe     |qwe     |March-01-2016

2    |asd     |gfh     |March-03-2016

3    |zxc     |vbn     |March-05-2016
```

**order**

```
o_id|cu_id|cu_dateorder

1   |1    |03-05-2016

2   |2    |03-10-2016

3   |2    |03-13-2016

4   |3    |03-20-2016

5   |1    |04-23-2016
```

**I want to display the customer with single order.**

Comment: Please add **what have you tried so far**, **expected output** **HINT:** `INNER JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT`

Comment: You might look for SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Select x * from orders x left join orders y on y.cu_id = x.cu_id and y.o_id < x.o_id where y.o_id is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.cu_id,c.cu_fname,c.cu_lname,c.cu_datacreated,o.o_id,o.cu_dateorder
from customer c
inner join order o on c.cu_id = o.cu_id
group by o.cu_id
having count(o.o_id)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.cu_id,a.cu_fname from customer a join order b on a.cu_id = b.cu_id
group by b.cu_id having count(cu_id) = 1;
```

Result set will be grouped by customer id and it will show results only where
count of cu_id is 1, should solve the purpose.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.